# getmimetype returning null in signed apk after adding proguard

Tags: android, proguard, signed

Here getmimetype method returning null in signed apk.
App works perfect in debug mode.
Review code and give advice to resolve this issue.

```
 public static String getMimeType(String path) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
    if (extension != null) {
        type =MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

and also

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: You can't simply add proguard. You have to write proguard rules to avoid the classes where app is crashing. Rules can be written in proguard file.

Comment: I think you are getting issue from proguard, if I am right then you need to implement serializable in that class which is throwing exception. or you can set -keep class.... in proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: @Shivam i have already write proguard rules to avoid classes,but i m still getting nullpointer exception.